# Modify value of each element represented by emi

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML snippet

```
 <td id = "bank2.loan1">
 <form:input path="bankDetails[1].EMIofRunningLoan1" size = "12" id = "bankDetails1_EMIofRunningLoan1" cssClass = "emi"/>
 </td>
 <th id = "bank2.loanText2">
 Running&nbsp;Loan&nbsp;2
 </th>
 <td id = "bank2.loan2">
 <form:input path="bankDetails[1].EMIofRunningLoan2" size = "12" id = "bankDetails1_EMIofRunningLoan2" cssClass = "emi"/>
 </td>
 <th id = "bank2.loanText3">
 Running&nbsp;Loan&nbsp;3
 </th>
 <td id = "bank2.loan3">
 <form:input path="bankDetails[1].EMIofRunningLoan3" size = "12" id = "bankDetails1_EMIofRunningLoan3" cssClass = "emi"/>
 </td>
 <th id = "bank2.loanText4">
 Running&nbsp;Loan&nbsp;4
 </th>
 <td id = "bank2.loan4">
 <form:input path="bankDetails[1].EMIofRunningLoan4" size = "12" id = "bankDetails1_EMIofRunningLoan4" cssClass = "emi"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th id = "bank2.loanText5">
 Running&nbsp;Loan&nbsp;5
 </th>
 <td id = "bank2.loan5">
 <form:input path="bankDetails[1].EMIofRunningLoan5" size = "12" id = "bankDetails1_EMIofRunningLoan5" cssClass = "emi"/>
 </td>
  <th id = "bank2.loanText6">
 Running&nbsp;Loan&nbsp;6
 </th>
 <td id = "bank2.loan6">
 <form:input path="bankDetails[1].EMIofRunningLoan6" size = "12" id = "bankDetails1_EMIofRunningLoan6" cssClass = "emi"/>
 </td>
  <th id = "bank2.loanText7">
 Running&nbsp;Loan&nbsp;7
 </th>
 <td id = "bank2.loan7">
 <form:input path="bankDetails[1].EMIofRunningLoan7" size = "12" id = "bankDetails1_EMIofRunningLoan7" cssClass = "emi"/>
 </td>
```

I want to reset value of each element having class = emi with 0.0. Have a look at my jQuery snippet. This does not seem to work. I am calling the function resetForm() .

```
function resetForm() {
           $('.emi').each(function() {
                $(this).val('0.0');
            });
        }
```

Comment: You should just be able to use: `$('.emi').val('0.0')`, where is `resetForm()` being called? @Sergio - it's ASP.NET markup, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx

Comment: it should work fine... can you share the generated html... but it can be rewritten as `$('.emi').val('0.0');`

Answer (score 0):

The following code would work properly :

```
function resetForm() {
           $('.emi').val("0.0");
        }
```